# Android MediaPlayer only playing first 2 files

Tags: java, android

im developing an exercise app with a little **MediaPlayer** while working out, before that, the user can choose the songs he wants to listen while working out, even if i select 3 o more, the **MediaPlayer** only plays the first 2, hope you can help me

**Playlist_Picker.java**

Here the users picks the songs he wants to listen

```
    public class Playlist_Picker extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    String[] items;
    Button clean,done;
    long[] selected;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playlist__picker);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvPlaylist);
        clean = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clean);
        clean.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        done = (Button)findViewById(R.id.done);


        final ArrayList<File> mySongs = findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        items = new String[mySongs.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i<mySongs.size(); i++){
            items[i]= mySongs.get(i).getName().toString().replace(".mp3","").replace(".mp3","");

        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,android.R.id.text1,items);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lv.setAdapter(adp);
        done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int choice = lv.getCount();
                selected = new long[choice];
                for (int i = 0; i<choice ; i++){
                    selected[i]=-1;
                }
                SparseBooleanArray spa = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for (int i = 0; i < choice; i++){
                    if (spa.get(i)){
                        selected[i] = lv.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
                    }
                }

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Workout.class).putExtra("pos",selected).putExtra("songlist",mySongs) );
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void toast(String text){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public ArrayList<File> findSongs(File root){
        ArrayList<File> al = new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files = root.listFiles();
        for(File singleFile : files){
            if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()){
                al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));
            }
            else{
                if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav")){
                    al.add(singleFile);
                }
            }
        }

        return al;
    }
}
```

**WorkingOut.java**

here i get the array and play the files, but the OnCompletitionListener is only working 1 time, even if there more than 2 files

```
if (mp!=null){
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }

        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle b = i.getExtras();
        mySongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");
        position = b.getLongArray("pos");
        playlist = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int j = 0; j < mySongs.size(); j++){
            if (j == position[j]){
                playlist.add(mySongs.get(j));
//                x++;
            }
        }

        u = Uri.parse(playlist.get(x).toString());
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);

//        sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        String Songname = playlist.get(x).getName().toString().replace(".mp3","");
        song_name.setText(Songname);
        btPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        updateSeekBar.start();
        int playlist_size = playlist.size();
        if (playlist_size>1){
//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//
//                    "mas de 1 cancion",
//
//                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
                    x = (x+1)%playlist.size();
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(x),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    u = Uri.parse(playlist.get(x).toString());
                    String Songname = playlist.get(x).getName().toString().replace(".mp3","");
                    song_name.setText(Songname);
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
//                    updateSeekBar.start();
                    mp.start();
//                    sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());

                }
            });
        }else{
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.release();
//                    x = 0;
                    u = Uri.parse(playlist.get(x).toString());
                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),u);
                    mp.start();
//                    sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only adding the completion listener to the first MediaPlayer which you subsequently destroy. So you didn't add another one to the current one. Which is both silly because why are you releasing it, you still need one. And the solution might be to call mp.setOnCompleteionListner(this) within that loop.

Properly you should only add the completionListener once. And you should keep the instance of MediaPlayer around and not .release() it all the time. You want to use it to play other songs, so keep the one you have.

I suggest you study the state diagram. [image: mediaplayer state diagram]

What you actually need to do is add proper hooks to get this to get back after it's done to load up the next song and play it within the current listener until the queue is finished and then go ahead and die out, or replay or whatever you want. The core problem is you add the mediaplayer completion listener that one time, that sets up the next song after the current song completes by destroying the media player you had and making an new one (without the completion listener on that one). This causes it to finish the first song, trigger the listener, start the second song and then out because there's no completion listener on the second one.